# Swift 3 tableview.reloadData on main thread, not displaying cells properly

Tags: multithreading, uitableview, swift3

In a simple TableViewController i am calling ClouKit deleteRecord in a UIAlertController.

```
    // 2. When the user clicks OK.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        LSCloudKit.shared.deleteRecord(record: login.toCKRecord(), completion: { (success) in
            let index = self.logins.index(of: login);
            self.logins.remove(at: index!);
            self.tableView.reloadData(); // <-problem is here. Data not displayed properly
        });
    }));
```

When i call self.tableView.reloadData(), the table seems to update but it display the wrong list, ie: twice the same cell, sometimes its the one that got deleted and sometimes its another one.

I checked that the call is being made on the main thread. 
Here is the deleteRecord function too:

```
func deleteRecord(record: CKRecord!, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let container = CKContainer.default();
    let privateDatabase = container.privateCloudDatabase;

    privateDatabase.delete(withRecordID: record.recordID) { (recordID, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(error == nil)
        }
    }
}
```

If i put a breakpoint in xCode anywhere either inside DispatchQueue.main.async or inside the completion block of "deleteRecord", then everything appears fine on the device once i hit "continue".

The problem happens on simulator and real devices as well.

Please help.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Adding screenshot

Here is the screenshot before and after deleting "user1" from the list, with the output:

self.logins before delete: [admin, master, user1, user2, user3]

self.logins after delete: [admin, master, user2, user3]

[Before delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6LhE.png)

[After delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSIpv.png)

Comment: Have you tried putting this code: `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` block also?

Comment: One more thing you dont need to put `;` at the end of a single statement in swift

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Yes i did try the Dispatch,main.async block around the reloadData() call.

Comment: I would suggest to add this statement: `print(self.logins)` before and after this code `self.logins.remove(at: index!)` and see what it prints? is the output that you expect ?

Comment: I added screenshot and output like you sugested in the original post

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the problem by using this instead of reloadData()

```
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: index!, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

I will not mark this as the right answer for a while since it is a work around and i still dont understand why reloadData() did not work. Its annoying me.